# Wrap tooltip with the last word of the preceding text block

Tags: html, css

I have a title in a h tag and a tooltip that is outside the h tag. I want to keep the tooltip from wrapping and being on a line by itself.

But I can only achieve it by putting the tooltip as a span inside the h tag. But, in my application, the tooltip module is inside a div so it cannot be placed inside the h tag.

A possible solution I have thought of is injecting a few & nbsp ; at the end of the h tag and making the h tag's margin-right negative to pull up the tooltip. But I am unsure if this will cause layout issues.

I came across the <nobr></nobr> which seems to be what I want, but it seems to not be an offical tag and doesn't have good support.

```css
.container{
  background-color: #f2f2fa;
  display:block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.con1{
  width: 263px;
}
.con2{
  width: 190px;
}
.con3{
    width: 300px;
}
h4{
  display: inline;
  line-height: 25px;
}
.nobr{
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.aster{
  color: #fc3256;
}
.tooltip{
  display: inline;
  background-color: #4051c6;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 2px 8px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="container con1">
  <h4>I have a title in a h tag and a tooltip that is outside the h tag. I want to keep the tooltip from wrapping and being on a line by itself, but <span class="nobr">how&nbsp;?<span class="aster">*</span></span></h4>
  <div class="tooltip">i</div>
</div>


<div class="container con2">
  <h4>I can keep things inside the h tag together with a <span class="nobr">span&nbsp;!<span class="aster">*</span></span></h4>
</div>


<div class="container con3">
  <h4>This is a mock up of my desired <span class="nobr">result&nbsp;!<span class="aster">*</span> <div class="tooltip">i</div></span></h4>
</div>
```